# jQuery Grid showing no any items, despite controller action returning correct json data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

Here's my client-side code:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "/Entry/EntryListingByBreed/",
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "POST",
        postData: { showId: showId, breedId: breedId },
        colNames: ["Class", "NZKC Reg", "Registered name", "Date of birth", "Entered"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "ClassNumber", sortable: false, width: 50 },
            { name: "NZKCRegistration", sortable: false, width: 100 },
            { name: "RegisteredName", sortable: false, width: 200 },
            { name: "DateOfBirth",  sortable: false, width: 200 },
            { name: "Entered", sortable: false, width: 200 }
        ],
        pager: jQuery("#pager"),
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [10, 20, 40],
        altRows: true,
        altclass: "gridAltRow",
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: "Entries for " + breedName
    });
```

and here is my server-side code:

```
 [RequiresAuthentication]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EntryListingByBreed(int showId, int breedId, string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
        {
            using (var dataContext = new NZDogShowsEntities())
            {
                int pageIndex = page - 1;
                int pageSize = rows;
                var entries = from se in dataContext.ShowEntries
                              where se.ShowID == showId && se.Entry.BreedID == breedId
                              select se;
                int totalRecords = entries.Count();
                int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
                var showEntries = (from se in dataContext.ShowEntries.AsEntryListingAggregate().AsEnumerable()
                                   where se.ShowID == showId && se.Entry.BreedID == breedId
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       ID = se.ID,
                                       ClassNumber = se.Class.Number.ToString(),
                                       NZKCRegistration = se.Entry.NZKCRegNumber,
                                       RegisteredName = se.Entry.RegisteredName,
                                       DateOfBirth = se.Entry.DateOfBirth.GetValueOrDefault().ToLongDateString(),
                                       Entered = se.Entry.DateOfBirth.GetValueOrDefault().ToLongDateString()
                                   }).ToList();

                var jsonData = new
                {
                    total = totalPages,
                    page = page,
                    records = totalRecords,
                    rows = (
                    from entry in showEntries
                    select new
                    {
                        i = entry.ID,
                        cell = new string[]{
                            entry.ClassNumber,
                            entry.NZKCRegistration,
                            entry.RegisteredName,
                            entry.DateOfBirth,
                            entry.Entered
                        }
                    }).ToArray()
                };

                var viewData = Json(jsonData);
                return viewData;
            }
        }
    }
```

My server-side code looks a bit more verbose than necessary but it was good while I'm troubleshooting. The `viewData` variable is showing all the right data, number of rows, page number, etc. etc.

The grid is formatted, ie. showing all the chrome surround, etc. However, no data is shown. Even the "Page x of y" is not correct. It's showing "Page 0 of" and the `<span>` where total number of records should show is blank. I'm at a lost here - probably missing something terribly obvious, especially since I'm a newbie to all this.

Any help/pointers (pun-intended) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: Ok, the above server-side code has been fixed and now produces JSON string. It appears to be correctly formatted. I won't update the above code but will provide the JSON string below. It parses correctly but still Firebug reports "invalid label". The grid is not being populated either! Here's the string - can't for the life of me spot the problem:

```
{"total":2,"page":1,"records":25,"rows":[{"id":2,"cell":["2a","1234567","Test Dog","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":3,"cell":["4a","abcdef","Test Dog 2","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":4,"cell":["5a","abc123","Test Dog 3","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":5,"cell":["6a","asdf890","Test Dog X","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":6,"cell":["6","qwerty","Test Dog Y","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":7,"cell":["1","fw3asd","Test Dog 4","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":8,"cell":["10","asdfa","Test Dog 5","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":9,"cell":["11a","houh2","Test Dog 6","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":11,"cell":["8","xxxx","Test X","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":12,"cell":["8","zzzz","Test Z","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":13,"cell":["1","qqqq","Test Q","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":14,"cell":["8a","tttt","Test T","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":15,"cell":["8a","rrrr","Test R","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":16,"cell":["7","aaaa","Test A","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":17,"cell":["1","11223344","Test Entry","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":18,"cell":["1","66778899","asdfa","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":19,"cell":["1","13o24bo","qwlen;oq","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":20,"cell":["1","oubiou","asdfa","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":21,"cell":["1","o2no3","hohohop","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]},{"id":22,"cell":["1","o48t2","Test 09808","Monday, 1 January 0001","Monday, 1 January 0001"]}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem - someone else working on this code has upgraded the main jquery library to 1.5. Obviously something is not backward compatible! I replaced it back with 1.4.4 and everything worked instantly!

Comment: Please test with jQuery 1.5.1rc1 to see if the issue has been fixed: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/02/18/jquery-1-5-1-rc-1-released/ . If it has not, please report on the jQuery bug tracker http://bugs.jquery.com/newticket . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know jquery tends to freak out when the JSON data isn't formatted perfect, I would check out in firebug what the return data looks like, and make sure all the properties are formatted with double quotes.

Also, the only other thing I can think of is that it's not inside of $.ready(function { ... });

Comment: Hmm...good point...but the Json() method handles the serialisation, right? That has never failed me before - always returns correctly formatted Json string. It actually is inside $(document).ready(...) along with other functions. I just didn't include the outer bits. That part definitely works since the grid appears, but just the outer chrome bits (column header and pager), no rows inside it.

Comment: that's all i can think of, but i would also make sure theres no errors in the console, although you prob already did that. generally when stuff isn't working at that point, i usually look around for any uses of js eval since it often doesnt log stuff correctly. if still no luck, maybe try with just 1 row of data. sorry i cant be more help :<

Comment: Hang on, you may be able to help yet :o) I just peeked a bit more carefully at Firebug and it has an "invalid label http://localhost/Entry/Create/10/1
Line 0" error! Not entirely sure what that means. I have never really debug JSON stuff with Firebug before...